# CF Route-Service downtime makes app unreachable

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a user provided route-service in CF which I bind with my application. Every time my route-service is down, my application is unreachable, although its up and running fine. Is there a way out that CF provides, in case route-service goes down, but my application is reachable.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this. For most use cases for route services that come to my mind (authentication, authorization, throttling), this would also not make sense. I would invest the time to make my route service more stable. In case it fails often, it might be too complex? Violating the single responsibility principle? Why is it failing?

Comment: In case this happens during deployment of the route service, you should consider blue-green deployment for your route service.

Comment: @user152468 I am using it for throttling. Agree with you on blue-green during deployment. I was looking for a workaround, when thing goes wrong for a single instance after deployment.